# Error: java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()

Tags: java, base-de-datos

Hola soy novato en Java y estoy aprendiendo el acceso a bbdd y me da este error y no encuentro la solución:

> java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

El código es el siguiente:

```
JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Borrar");
btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        
        String nombre = textField.getText();
        
        try {       
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        java.sql.Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/universidad","root","");
        
        java.sql.Statement statement = conexion.createStatement();
        
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("DELETE FROM alumnos WHERE nombre="+nombre);
        statement.executeUpdate(nombre);
        conexion.close();
        /*String matricula = textField.getText();
        ((java.sql.Statement)statement).executeUpdate("Select nombre from alumnos where matricula= '"+ matricula +"');*/
        
            //textField.setText(resultSet.getString("nombre"));
           // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha Borrado" +id+ "de la BD");
            
        
        conexion.close(); 
            
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException el) {
            el.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Las consultas `INSERT, UPDATE o DELETE` no se ejecutan con `executeQuery()` sino con [`executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)), intenta así: `ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM alumnos WHERE nombre="+nombre);`  y también, borra la línea que sigue: `statement.executeUpdate(nombre);` la cual no tiene ningún sentido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay al menos dos errores en tu código:

1. JDBC dispone del método [`executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) para las consultas de tipo `INSERT`, `DELETE` o `UPDATE`, no puedes usar `executeQuery()` para este tipo de consultas.
2. Por otra parte, estas consultas no devuelven un `ResultSet` (un conjunto de resultados) sino simplemente un valor entero que indicaría el resultado de dichas consultas, con dos posibilidades:

   - Un valor `N` que sería el total de filas afectadas por la consulta
   - El valor `0` si la consulta no retorna nada (por ejemplo si no borra ningún registro).

   Para más detalles sobre esto consulta la documentación en el enlace de más arriba.

También, debo señalar que tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL. Deberías usar consultas preparadas para blindar el código.

Te propongo esta solución:

```
try {       
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    java.sql.Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/universidad","root","");
    
    java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = conexion.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM alumnos WHERE nombre=?");
    pst.setString(1, nombre);
    int deletedRows = pst.executeUpdate();
    //Usar deletedRows si fuera preciso                
    conexion.close();
```

Señalo también que desde JDBC 4.0 en adelante ya no es necesario el uso de `Class.forName`, como dice la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefjdbc4_0summary.html):

> Autoloading of JDBC drivers. In earlier versions of JDBC, applications
> had to manually register drivers before requesting Connections. With
> JDBC 4.0, applications no longer need to issue a `Class.forName()` on
> the driver name; instead, the `DriverManager` will find an appropriate
> JDBC driver when the application requests a Connection.

---

> Autocarga de drivers JDBC. En versiones anteriores de JDBC, las
> aplicaciones tenían que registrar manualmente los controladores antes
> de solicitar conexiones. Con JDBC 4.0, las aplicaciones ya no
> necesitan usar `Class.forName()` para indicar el nombre del
> controlador; en su lugar, `DriverManager` encontrará un controlador
> JDBC adecuado cuando la aplicación solicite una conexión.

Comment: Muchas Gracias A. Cedano, siempre ayudándonos, no sé como agradecerte.